# How to read xml file and save it in a string

Tags: xml, xamarin

How to read all the contents of my xml url and write to a string, I want it to come in the way it is shown in the xml, I do not want to separate it in.

My string will look this way

```
string xml = @"<rss version="2.0"><channel>
       <title>exemplo</title>

       <title>exemplo</title>
      <link>exemplo</link>
     </image>
    <item>
  exemplo
    <title>
     <![CDATA[
   exemplo
    ]]>
     </title>
   <link>
      <![CDATA[
   exemplo
     ]]>
     </link>
      <description>exemplo</description>
      <pubDate>Tue, 05 Aug 2017 21:21:28 GMT</pubDate>
       </item>"
```

I tried this more without the expected result

```
  XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("url");
            string xml = doc.ToString();
```

Comment: Jose...what is the result you get and what do you expect? Normally to convert an xDocument to a string is via ToSteing()...that's why I am asking you:)

Comment: if you don't want to parse it, just use File.ReadAllText()

Comment: I want my string to receive the complete xml file, at the moment when I will check my xml variable is null, blank

Comment: Yes I do not want parsed, how to put File.ReadAllText () next to my command

Comment: string xml = File.ReadAllText(path_to_file);

Comment: I forgot to put a note, I'm using xamarin forms

Comment: The  File.ReadAllText  function is not supported in xamarin forms and only supported on android

Comment: you can implement it in your platform project and use DI to access it from Forms, or try using the PCLStorage package